# Allowing Hindi fonts in html text area

Tags: java, fonts, textarea, hindi, non-english

I have a desktop application in java that converts from literal `hindi` text to corresponding english `translitration`. I am using `jTextArea` in desktop application. Now I want to make a web application for doing the same. My end goal is to have two text areas in html in one of which I can type hindi characters and in other one would show translitration result in english characters at the same time. For Hindi I want to use `kruti dev` font and `Times new roman` for english.

Comment: That's nice.  have a look at http://www.bing.com/translator/Default.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to create a new one, when there are many with such facilities? ;) you can use `aksharamukha` tool. If you still want to create on your own, you can write a simple code on JavaScript or jquery and fetch text from one textbox and replace each character by roman or Devanagari text and paste the text in another box. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Cufon: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Keep in mind any license issues regarding font usage before making use of a font.

If you want a safe approach, try and find a font you're happy with here: https://www.google.com/fonts

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.

instead of setting

```
input.value = "Hindi Text";
```

which shows up as utf-8 notations in textarea, do -

```
input.innerHTML = "Hindi Text";
```

It works for me